# Strategy for Filling Empty Cells in Android GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout

[image]

I'm building a tablet Android app with a scrolling mosaic with tiles of various sizes (3x2, 1x1, 1x2, etc.), similar to the image above.

I'm building the horizontally-scrolling view in "blocks of 15", using multiple 5x3 [GridLayouts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

My problem is that while I'm able to get the correct number of total cells to fill each GridLayout block, unless I get lucky with the ordering of the tiles, I'm inevitably left with gaps with empty cells and a couple 1x1s rendered off screen.

Is there a strategy for ordering the insertion of tiles to ensure each block of 15 has every cell filled?  Or a way to inspect a GridLayout after the fact to manually fill any empty cells?

Comment: I remember the old google play store screen(samsung) with a similar grid of images having the same problem with sometimes empty spaces on the grid. Interestingly they'd just let that space be with the original background of the play store and it didnt really effect the overall UI and sometimes just looked cooler. Something you can explore if you dont really get a tech ans to solve this. Technically you can try `android:layout_columnSpan="1"` `android:layout_rowSpan="1"` for all children and prevent a colfrom stretching by ensuring that one of the components in the col does not define gravity

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to h[image]ave a look at the apps like "launcher8" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lx.launcher8

This app has the same kind of UI you need,

....and open the DDMS view in eclipse and use the hierarchy viewer to see the layout hierarchy and so you can get the hint to create a view hierarchy like this.

steps

1. first open devices in ddms view of eclipse
   [image]
2. then click on hierarchy viewer to capture the layout.
   [image]

after this you will get a screen just as your phone is displaying at that point,just hover over any area to see the complete hierarchy of it.

*

- conclusion

You will see the layout hierarchy on your right as you can see that it uses no grid view it just uses a combination of linearlayout framelayout.
*

hope it helps you.

Comment: You can be able to see the layout hierarchy it uses to make such a layout..so thats how this can  be of help

Comment: you give me the app you want to have same layout as....ill post the hierarchy over here

Comment: so for a layout like in the app i specified in the link above...i have uploaded the pic it has my hand made layout for...try to understand it..